# SwiftUI preview crashes when extending View

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, swiftui

I have a project that needs to support an old version of iOS and I'm trying to use SwiftUI for a view that will only appear when the user is on iOS 13 or later. The SwiftUI Preview in Xcode works just fine, but when I extend a SwiftUI struct (such as View), the project will compile and run on a device, but the Preview Canvas crashes, stating that it `Failed to build myView.swift`. When I click on the "diagnostics" button, it tells me that `'View' is only available in iOS 13.0 or newer` and `add @available attribute to enclosing extension`. However, the extension in question already has `@available(iOS 13.0, *)` before it. For example:

```swift
@available(iOS 13.0, *)
extension View {
    func myFunc() {

    }
}
```

In an effort to find the root of this problem, I noticed that the preview won't crash if it's completely empty. Only once I add a function or static property to it will the canvas crash. I have also tried adding the `@available` line before each function in the extension, rebooting my computer, and deleting the DerivedData folder, but it doesn't seem to have made a difference.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need `@available(iOS 13.0, *)` your app won't run on any device below version `13.0` so basically the error is stating this is redundant. Removing it should fix your issue.

However if you are doing SwiftUI weak linking and this issue is there then it's a known bug with xCode. If no weak linking then please remove `@available(iOS 13.0, *)`

EDIT: it seems like you have weak linking.

1. Make sure `SwiftUI.framework` is set to `optional` in `Build Phases -> Link Binary With Libraries`
2. Make sure your `@available(iOS 13.0, *)` is on top of your `body` not on top of your extension

example:

```
struct TestView2: View {
    @available(iOS 13.0, *)
    var body: some View {
        Text("test")
    }
}

extension TestView2 {
    func abc() {

    }
}

struct TestView2_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    @available(iOS 13.0, *)
    static var previews: some View {
        TestView2()
    }
}
```

Comment: The app is targeting an older version of iOS, but the view in question is only meant to appear if the user is running 13.0 or later. Without `@available(iOS 13.0, *)` , the app wouldn't compile at all.

Comment: Got it, I edited my answer to reflect. Please check it.

Comment: I am using weak linking, and I added `@available(iOS 13.0, *)` to the top of my body, (instead of above the struct), but it still doesn't work. As you mentioned, this appears to be an Xcode bug, so I can only hope it gets fixed soon.

Comment: The above code works fine for me, I am able to preview and I have targeted iOS 12.4. Anyways, if there is anything else I can help you with please let me know.

Comment: It could be that the issue is that I'm trying to extend SwiftUI's built-in `View` struct, while your code is extending `TestView2`.

Comment: My apologies, I did miss that point. Yes you are 100% correct, you are extending View struct which is causing the issue, but yes it's xcode's issue. Hopefully we hear something form Apple this month in their event.

Comment: This doesn't work for me either. We're just going to have to wait for Apple to fix this. Did you file a bug report?

Comment: @UncommentedCode, `View` from SwiftUI is not a `struct`, but rather a `protocol` to which a struct can be made to conform. It's definitely acceptable to extend a protocol, including the `View` protocol from SwiftUI, to say, add a method to it. In fact, such a practice is very common :)!

Answer (score 0):

### Discussion

The following code example works well for me. Please note the `@available(iOS 13.0, *)` declaration attributes for not *only* the `View` extension, but **also** for:

1. The `ContentView` struct, which conforms to the `View` protocol,

**and**

2. The `ContentView_Previews` struct, which conforms to the `PreviewProvider` protocol.

FYI: I set my Xcode Project's deployment target to iOS 12.4 for my test.

### Code Example

```swift
import SwiftUI

@available(iOS 13.0, *)
extension View {
    func overlayText<Content>(_ content: Content) -> some View where Content : StringProtocol {
        overlay(Text(content))
    }
}

@available(iOS 13.0, *)
struct ContentView: View {
    static private var initialGreeting = "Hello World!"
    static private var greetings: [String] {
        [
            initialGreeting,
            "Hey Everyone!",
            "Hi Everybody!",
            "Hello Friends!"
            
        ]
    }
    @State private var greeting = initialGreeting
    
    var body: some View {
        Button(action: { [greeting] in
            while self.greeting == greeting {
                self.greeting = Self.greetings.randomElement()!
            }
        }) {
            Color.green
                .overlayText(greeting)
                .cornerRadius(30)
                .padding(5)
        }
        .background(Color.black)
        .frame(height: 50)
        .foregroundColor(.white)
        .font(.system(size: 28, weight: .bold))
        .cornerRadius(30)
        .padding()
    }
}

@available(iOS 13.0, *)
struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ContentView()
    }
}
```